# Prevent duplicate entries while inserting through other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I need to extract some column values from `T2` and insert them into `T3` by looping through `T1`. And ofcourse I must avoid the duplicate entries in `T3`.

**My tables:**

[image: My tables]

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
    Id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE T2 (
    Id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FK_T1 BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    Desc VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    UNIQUE KEY FK_T1 (FK_T1),
    CONSTRAINT FK_T2_T1 FOREIGN KEY (FK_T1) REFERENCES T1 (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE T3 (
    Id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FK_T1 BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    T2Desc VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    UNIQUE KEY FK_T1 (FK_T1),
    CONSTRAINT FK_T3_T1 FOREIGN KEY (FK_T1) REFERENCES T1 (Id)
);
```

**Data:**

```
T1
+----+
| Id |
+----+
| 11 |
| 12 |
+----+

T2
+----+-------+--------+
| Id | FK_T1 | Desc   |
+----+-------+--------+
| 21 | 11    | desc 1 |
| 22 | 12    | desc 2 |
+----+-------+--------+

T3
+----+-------+--------+
| Id | FK_T1 | T2Desc |
+----+-------+--------+
| xx | 11    | desc 1 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

I would expect a new row to be added into `T3` when I execute the following query but it gives `Duplicate entry '11' for key 'FK_T1'` error ofcourse:

```
-- expected new row to be added => | xx | 12 | desc 2 |

INSERT INTO T3(FK_T1, T2Desc)  (
    SELECT t2.FK_T1, t2.Desc
    FROM T2 t2
    INNER JOIN T1 t1 ON t1.Id = t2.FK_T1
);
```

How can I make this query work with a clear extension? May be by using `LEFT JOIN` so that I can even also filter the `T1` first with something like `WHERE T1.Id > 10`?

Comment: Desc is a reserved word in MySQL, so something above is not quite right

Comment: What do you think about Transaction and SELECT .. FOR UPDATE/SHARE .... ?

Comment: Ups: see manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: @Strawberry sorry, my bad, it was just to show a very short example. thank you for warning.

Comment: @BerndBuffen Sorry, I don't see how `locking reads` will help to skip the exist rows while inserting. I think a simple query will be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use this Query without INGORE. This only selects the rows that are not in table3 and insert.

```
INSERT INTO T3 (FK_T1, T2Desc)
SELECT T2.FK_T1, t2.Desc
FROM T2 T2 
JOIN T1 T1 ON T1.Id = T2.FK_T1
LEFT JOIN T3 T3 ON T2.FK_t1 = T3.FK_T1 
WHERE T3.FK_T1 IS NULL;
```

**SAMPLE**
  see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b256ba0b1e226cc9f54b65c26f812362)

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
    Id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);
CREATE TABLE T2 (
    Id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FK_T1 BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `Desc` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    UNIQUE KEY FK_T1 (FK_T1),
    CONSTRAINT FK_T2_T1 FOREIGN KEY (FK_T1) REFERENCES T1 (Id)
);
CREATE TABLE T3 (
    Id BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FK_T1 BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    T2Desc VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    UNIQUE KEY FK_T1 (FK_T1),
    CONSTRAINT FK_T3_T1 FOREIGN KEY (FK_T1) REFERENCES T1 (Id)
);
```

**add Rows**

```
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (11),(12);
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (21, 11, 'desc 1'), (22, 12, 'desc 2');
INSERT INTO T3 VALUES (31, 11, 'desc 1');
```

**Update T3**

```
mysql> INSERT INTO T3 (FK_T1, T2Desc)
    -> SELECT T2.FK_T1, T2.Desc
    -> FROM T2 T2
    -> JOIN T1 T1 ON T1.Id = T2.FK_T1
    -> LEFT JOIN T3 T3 ON T2.FK_t1 = T3.FK_T1
    -> WHERE T3.FK_T1 IS NULL;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

**see Result**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM T3;
+----+-------+--------+
| Id | FK_T1 | T2Desc |
+----+-------+--------+
| 31 |    11 | desc 1 |
| 32 |    12 | desc 2 |
+----+-------+--------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**insert new row and test**

```
mysql> INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (33),(34);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO T2 VALUES (41, 33, 'desc 33'), (51, 34, 'desc 34');
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>


mysql> INSERT INTO T3 (FK_T1, T2Desc)
    -> SELECT T2.FK_T1, T2.Desc
    -> FROM T2 T2
    -> JOIN T1 T1 ON T1.Id = T2.FK_T1
    -> LEFT JOIN T3 T3 ON T2.FK_t1 = T3.FK_T1
    -> WHERE T3.FK_T1 IS NULL;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM T3;
+----+-------+---------+
| Id | FK_T1 | T2Desc  |
+----+-------+---------+
| 31 |    11 | desc 1  |
| 32 |    12 | desc 2  |
| 33 |    33 | desc 33 |
| 34 |    34 | desc 34 |
+----+-------+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**try query again without tablechanges**

```
mysql> INSERT INTO T3 (FK_T1, T2Desc)
    -> SELECT T2.FK_T1, T2.Desc
    -> FROM T2 T2
    -> JOIN T1 T1 ON T1.Id = T2.FK_T1
    -> LEFT JOIN T3 T3 ON T2.FK_t1 = T3.FK_T1
    -> WHERE T3.FK_T1 IS NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql>
```

Comment: In your first query code you meant `T1` instead of `T!` I think.

Answer (score 2):

Test

```sql
INSERT IGNORE INTO T3 (FK_T1, T2Desc)
SELECT T2.FK_T1, T2.`Desc`
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.Id = T2.FK_T1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=123350bffdbc9043d71d3b4a4c5761bd)

PS. It is a bad idea to use reserved word `Desc` as a fieldname.

Comment: What I understand is this query will give an error/warning anyway which will be ignored. I really cannot convience my colleagues with that. A good thing to know of course but sorry..

Comment: @KorkiKorkig Yes, IGNORE converts error to warning. You may see this - simply add `SHOW WARNINGS;` immediately after inserting query. This is the regular method, analogous to `MERGE .. ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` or, in MySQL syntax, `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=id`.

Answer (score -1):

Using `INSERT IGNORE` can be expensive, especially if the table has a lot of rows or the data which you want to insert contains a lot of duplicates.

So why don't keep things simple and filter duplicates already in your select statement?

```
INSERT INTO T3 (FK_T1, T2Desc)
SELECT t2.FK_T1, t2.Desc1 FROM T2 t2 JOIN T3 t3 
  ON t2.FK_t1 != t3.FK_T1 
INNER JOIN T1 t1 ON t1.Id = t2.FK_T1
```

Comment: ON t2.FK_t1 != t3.FK_T1  selects all other rows